# How to change navigation drop down from hover to click

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, nav

I'm making a responsive navigation bar that has a dropdown that expands when you hover over it.  My problem is that this hover feature is not suitable for mobile devices.  As such, I am wanting to change my navigation bar to expand on click instead of on hover.

I have tried using the checkbox method but cannot get it to work.  I am wanting to only use HTML and CSS if it is possible.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

See it here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adilworth/1p8jL2t7/3/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#">Product 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">rx.com </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Copay Cards</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Product 2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">e.com </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Copay Cards</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Informational Video</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">INSOMNIA EDUCATION</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Complete Night Sleep Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sleep.com </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">PAIN MGMT EDUCATION</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Safer Pain Management Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">painmanagement.com </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">MEDICAL AFFAIRS</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Request Clinical Reprints</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Schedule a Scientific Session </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* Main Navigation */
#nav {
    position:relative;
    width:620px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    padding:10px;
}

ul#navigation {
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

ul#navigation li {
    display:inline;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

ul#navigation li a {
    width: 234px;
    padding:10px 25px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    background: #ebebeb;
}

ul#navigation li a:hover {
    background:#ebebeb;
    color:black;
}

ul#navigation li a.first {
    border-left: 0 none;
}

ul#navigation li a.last {
    border-right: 0 none;
}

ul#navigation li:hover > a {
    background:#ebebeb;
}

/* Drop-Down Navigation */
ul#navigation li:hover > ul
{
/*these 2 styles are very important,
being the ones which make the drop-down to appear on hover */
    display: block; /* here change visiblity > display */
    opacity:1;
}

ul#navigation ul, ul#navigation ul li ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
/*the next 2 styles are very important,
being the ones which make the drop-down to stay hidden */
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
    opacity:0;
    /*position: absolute; */
    display: none; /* change visibility > display */
    z-index: 99999;
    width:234px;
    background:#ebebeb;
}

ul#navigation ul {
    top: 43px;
    left: 1px;
}

ul#navigation ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 181px; /* strong related to width:180px; from above */
}

ul#navigation ul li {
    clear:both;
    width:55px;

}

ul#navigation ul li a {
    background:none;
    padding:7px 15px;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    border:0 none;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:150px;
}
```

Comment: If changes to the navigation bar are made by `:hover`, then on all devices that have a touchscreen, it will work as a click.

Comment: It sort of works but you have to tap off of the drop down for it to close.  You cannot tap on the nav to open the drop down then tap again on the same spot to close it

Comment: Yes that's right. Hover does not have the opposite effect when you click on an item on the task screen. Use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines at the bottom of your css file or tag.

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
.shown{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The html file:

```
<li>
  <a id="prod1" href="#">Product 1</a> 
  <ul id="prod1list" class="hidden"> 
    <li><a href="#">rx.com </a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Copay Cards</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</li>
<script>
    document.getElementById('prod1').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('prod1list').classList.toggle('shown');
    });
</script>
```

I tried it and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you!  This is very helpful